# Artifacts while sculpting

Tags: sculpting, dynamic-topology

I am trying to sculpt a human head with dynamic topology. It worked so far but now I am getting artifacts when I use the smooth brush.

[image: http://prntscr.com/2xsz9i]

And when I use the smooth brush

[image]

But other brushes like the clay brush are still working without causing those weird artifacts.
[image]

Any idea why this is happening?

[.blend file](http://www.pasteall.org/blend/27283)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure that under Symmetry \ Lock you turn Lock off. You had lock set to x axis. So the smooth brush was still working but the vertices did not move in the x axis.

[image]

Comment: Wow.. that was the problem. Thank you very much.

Comment: @MaikKlein yes. It took me some time to find out what the problem was as well. good thing you uploaded the blend file. At first I thought you had a nose texture for the smooth brush, but that was not it.